# settings needed for kafka-connect framework to achieve exactly once semantics

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am under the impression that in Kafka-Connect you can specify some parameters in the .properties files to turn on exactly-once semantics.

I have been unable to find these settings; but I have found other ways of achieving this like
https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/blogpost.md
and even older,
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ

Is it possible to achieve exactly once semantics by changing settings in kafka connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Connect does not support exactly once semantics at the framework scope. There are individual connectors (for instance the HDFS Connector that Confluent provides) that provide exactly once semantics. However, it's not a framework level configuration at this time.

Comment: can you provide a link to Confluent's HDFS Connector? I use kafka connect's hdfs connector.

Comment: This is the link to the connector hub in case you are interested in others. You'll find the hdfs connector that Confluent provides on top. http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/